# Table border isn't straight when I view it in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I try to make a simple email template in HTML. It looks good in Firefox and IE but in Outlook 2016 the left border line isn't straight.

I have added `border-collapse: collapse;` to my table otherwise the entire left line is missing in Outlook.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0xkqxxdh/

[image: Border]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding *font-size: 0px;* to any element that isn't filled with text.

Example:

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding: 20px 0 20px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;font-size: 0px;"><img alt="Logo" src="images/logo.png" style="display: block;font-size: 0px;"></td>
```

Adding *margin: 0px;* and *padding: 0px;* also help a great deal with tighter email layouts.

Also, you may want to try the oldest email trick in the book - surround the entire layout with a table that has a border and get rid of the bordered elements inside of it.  Then use a border-top for each additional section.

My guess is that, other than the *font-size*/*margin*/*padding* adjustments needed to make sure they aren't applied to a text-less section of the email (sounds "smexy"), that 2px border is forcing the extra pixels into the width.

E-Mails aren't friendly.  Clients who want them to be validated within Lotus Notes 7, are even worse.  If you haven't tried Litmus yet, go for the free trial when you have time to spend on some serious deep diving into the details of cross-client compatibility.  It's like meeting someone who wears a top hat and monocle on Miami Beach.